# Qgis2threejs initial zoom

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs

I'm looking for a method to change the initial view of the Qgis2threejs export. Is it very zoomed and I want less zoom when I open it.

Actually when I open the url is zommed:

[image]

But my idea is to have less initial zoom to see all the Italy. 
I didn't find any option into the files to change it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Qgis2threejs uses the map canvas extent by default when rendering the 3D view. In this case you can zoom out to the extent of Italy and use Qgis2threejs to render the canvas extent which will cover entire country. However, you need to adjust the resolution in order to get better quality when you do zoom in which will consume a lot of memory. Therefore, you have to balance between render quality and the size of the 3D map.

Comment: so, it depends from the view zoom on qgis before than export on Qgis2threejs and isn't editable after the rendering. thank you

Comment: Actually I never tried to edit the extent from inside the browser, but If I want to show the map at specific extent, I adjust everything in QGIS then export to 3D using the plugin.